# Android app development - Uri.parse - want not open browser

Tags: java, android

I have an Android program. I want to send request to a website, after which I need the server to run a command without going to the browser.

Is this possible? For example, at some point, my code is something like this:

```
Intent intent1 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("http://xxxxxxx);
```

Which of course opens the browser. How can this be avoided?

Comment: May be you are looking for HttpURLConnection instead of using Intent?

Comment: It works perfect with HttpURLConnection. Thank you.